# Gitlab unable to pass a variable inside the artifact

Tags: gitlab, yaml, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, artifact

I have a this yml file

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  tags: 
    - shared
  script:
    script:
    - if [ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "main" ]; then
        destination_dir=public;
      else
        destination_dir=test;
      fi
    - build -b html Document/Docs $destination_dir #stores the html in test folder
    - echo "$destination_dir"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $destination_dir
```

Here i am trying to get the variable value if the branch is main or not.

Suppose I am working in a feature branch and When I run the pipeline I get the log that "the document is created in test" but when the artifact part runs it generates error that "no files to upload". I want to change the folder name to test if the commit is not from the main branch. Seems like the variable is not passed in the artifact. Can someone tell me what else could be done here?

Comment: Whats the explicit path of the dir? artificats can only be uploaded if they exist in the build dir of the job.

Comment: i think the path should be test/index.html

Comment: what do you see if you just run `ls -lrt $destination_dir` after the echo command

Comment: I see "-rw-r--r-- 1 dockeruser dockeruser    2242 Apr 12 10:13 index.html"

Answer (score 0):

I do not find a specific reference for that but it look like this is not possible since the parsing of the variables in the job's yaml is done before the `script` runs.

I can suggest alternatives:

1. You can artifact both folders. It is not error to have non-existing folder in the artifacts list:

   ```
   artifacts:
     paths:
       - public
       - test
   ```
2. You can have fixed folder to artifact, for example `output`. Then create the folder `public` or `tests` inside it. The folder `output` and all its content will be in the artifacts and this include the folder `public` or `tests`.